# Flask button passing variable back to python

Tags: python, html, flask

I've found a lot of into similar to this, but I just can't quite make it work. Basically, I've got a button, and upon pressing it, I want to fire that value back to my flask backend.

HTML Button:

```
<form action="" method="POST" ><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete" value="{{  item2  }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</button> </form>
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def home():    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['delete'] == post_id:
            (my sql login/cursor stuff....)
            sql = "DELETE FROM test_table WHERE post_id = ?"
            c.execute(sql, (post_id,))
            return redirect("/")
```

As you can see, I'm populating the links (and subsequent variable) with jinja. It populated the button as it should, but sending it back to my python script isn't working.

**UPDATE:**
When I run this, I get an internal server error. I cannot see what the routing error is because I can't get debug to work (using wsgi/werkzeug).

I think we can conclusively say is that by not defining `post id` is why it's not working. So my question is, when the button sends data BACK to python, what value (and how) does python grab? is it `name=` or `value=` or something else?

Comment: Could you tell us more about what's not working? I created a simple view in an existing Flask app using your code, and it passed the test for `request_method == 'POST'`, and redirected me back to the `/` url. Clearly I removed the mysql stuff, and the test for the `post_id` value - but the parts that I can test appear to function correctly (including the value attribute of the button input).

Comment: When I click the button, I get the error:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: Marc, an "Internal Server Error" probably indicates some programming error in the route. You can probably get the traceback if you run the app interactively. As david mentioned, you did not define `post_id` -- That could be the ticket. Please update your question with any traceback or error messages. `app.debug=True` may also help.

Comment: "you did not define `post_id`" This is definitely the problem. I'm unsure how to get that value from the button. Would I pull this from the `name=` field or the `value=` field. 
As far as debugging goes, I'm using wsgi, and can't get it working with werkzeug.
Thank you for bearing with me. I am still new to Flask/Python.

Comment: to get value from button you need ie. `post_id = request.form['delete']`

Comment: If your code were valid and free of errors, getting the value by `request.form.get("delete")` would work. I don't doubt that you are getting the value back in your application. For kicks, try this under the `if request.method == 'POST'` just return the value -- `return request.form.get("delete")`

Comment: Yes great! Now I understand. The 'for kicks' suggestion did just what I hoped - returned the number. Now I can pass it down the line.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is

```
request.form['delete'] == post_id
```

You get value from button (`request.form['delete']`) and try to compare with value in variable `post_id` which doesn't exists.

If you want to get value from button and assign to variable `post_id` then you need

```
post_id = request.form['delete']
```

or

```
post_id = request.form.get('delete')
```

and then you can use `post_id` in SQL query.

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def home():    
    if request.method == 'POST':

        post_id = request.form.get('delete')

        if post_id is not None:
            (my sql login/cursor stuff....)
            sql = "DELETE FROM test_table WHERE post_id = ?"
            c.execute(sql, (post_id,))
            return redirect("/")
```

Comment: Awesome! This is basically what worked for me... The only difference was I had to do:
`sql = ("DELETE FROM test_table WHERE post_id=%s")`
 `c.execute(sql, (post_id_delete,) )`