# Flask - Submit a button value

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm using this form in Flask and it's working fine so far:

```
<form action = "/guess/" method = "post">
     <p>Your guess:</p>
     <p><input type = "text" name = "guess" /></p>
     <p><input type = "submit" value = "Submit" /></p>
     <p>{{ guess }}</p>
     <p>{{ used }}</p>
     <p>{{ user}}{{ score }}</p>
</form>
```

But is making button send string "example" to my script possible?

```
<form action = "/guess/" method = "post">
     <p>Your guess:</p>
     <p><input type = "text" name = "guess" /></p>
     <p><input type = "submit" value = "Submit" /></p>
     <p>{{ guess }}</p>
     <p>{{ used }}</p>
     <p>{{ user}}{{ score }}</p>
     <button type="submit" value="example" name="guess">Example</button>
</form>
```

I need to send certain string to my script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026510/flask-button-passing-variable-back-to-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask button passing variable back to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026510/flask-button-passing-variable-back-to-python)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it now, in my flask python script:

```
guess = request.form["guess"]
```

To request it's value. Duplicate request has to be removed:

```
<form action = "/guess/" method = "post">
 <p>Your guess:</p>
 <p>{{ guess }}</p>
 <p>{{ used }}</p>
 <p>{{ user}}{{ score }}</p>
 <button type="submit" value="example" name="guess">Example</button>
```